# IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1 - python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset with a list of quotes, like this

```
n agencyname paid(yes/not)

1 agencyA 1
2 agencyB 0
3 agencyC 0
4 agencyB 1
5 agencyA 0
6 agencyA 1
7 agencyB 1
...
```

I want to calculate the conversion rate of any agency, but I receive an error:
this is my code:

```
for value in set(df["agencyname"]):
        print("payd conversion rate for", value, "is:")
        print(df[(df["agencyname"]==value)]["paid"].value_counts()[1]/len(df[(df["agencyname"]==value)]["paid"]))
```

the result it works for the first agencies but more or less in the middle I have this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [627], in <cell line: 1>()
      1 for value in set(df["agencyname"]):
      2         print("payd rate for", value, "is:")
----> 3         print(df[(df["agencyname"]==value)]["paid"].value_counts()[1]/len(df[(df["agencyname"]==value)]["paid"]))

File ~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py:955, in Series.__getitem__(self, key)
    952     key = unpack_1tuple(key)
    954 if is_integer(key) and self.index._should_fallback_to_positional:
--> 955     return self._values[key]
    957 elif key_is_scalar:
    958     return self._get_value(key)

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

Comment: If something is size 1 you would index it with `0`.  `1` would be the index of the second item.

Comment: In python the first element in a list/pandas array is at index 0.  So you should change the `[1]` in the troublesome line to `[0]`.

Comment: `df[(df["agencyname"]==value)]["paid"]` can return an empty set or an unique item, so asking for the second item can raise an error